# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903 Cannot find yarn

Tags: node.js, package, homebrew, yarnpkg

Tried

```
brew uninstall yarn
brew uninstall node

rm -rf ./node-modules

brew install yarn
brew reinstall yarn
brew link yarn
```

and every possible other stackoverflow answer.

I still get the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/nachiketpusalkar/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.4.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:900:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an old package.json file in the root folder that was still pointing to an older version of Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

yarn webpack serve --mode development